# AngularJS state not working correctly in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, state

I'm new in Ionic and I have problem with **state**. I use Ionice tab template and I have few tabs. In one of the tab there is a link to another page. But 'state' doesn't work. It's probably something easy but I can't solve it.

My code is here (didn't connect it to ionic, just paste code). I want tab.read to work - the link to this page is in tab.dash.

```js
// Ionic Starter App
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  .state('account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.read', {
      url: '/read/:newsId',
      views: {
        'tab-dash': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-read.html',
          controller: 'ReadCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tab.informacje', {
      url: '/informacje',
      views: {
        'tab-informacje': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-informacje.html',
          controller: 'InformacjeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.zglos', {
    url: '/zglos',
    views: {
      'tab-zglos': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-zglos.html',
        controller: 'ZglosCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-view view-title="TestApp">
  <ion-content>

    <div class="news">

      <div class="list card" ng-repeat="item in news">
        <div class="item item-dark">
          <h2 class="light">{{ item.title }}</h2>
          <p class="dark-light">{{ item.date }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
            <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
            <button href="#/tab/read/{{ item.id }}" class="button button-small button-balanced">Przeczytaj całe</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Also account doesn't work correctly. But first I must solve problem with tab.read

Comment: use `ui-sref` to navigate `<button ui-sref="tab.read({newsId: {{item.id}} })" class="button button-small button-balanced">Przeczytaj całe</button>`

Comment: Thanks! It works. But why my method doesnt? Other tabs works fine these way.

Comment: please add the code of the other tabs, so that I can tell you the reason

Answer (score -1):

use **`ui-sref`** to navigate using `ui.router`,

```
<div class="item item-body">
   <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
   <button ui-sref="tab.read({newsId: {{item.id}} })" class="button button-small button-balanced">Przeczytaj całe</button>
</div>
```